# VSCode "Python: Select interpreter" add a custom path

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run a `python` executable that is a plugin to an application (Unreal Engine). When I do `CTRL + ALT + P` and do `select python interpreter` it only shows me the system installed python interpreter and the virtual envs. How can I add a searchpath?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a `python.pythonPath` setting in the *settings.json* file of your workspace.

From [Manually specify an interpreter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter):

> If VS Code does not automatically locate an interpreter you want to
> use, you can set the path to it manually in your Workspace Settings
> `settings.json` file. With any of the entries that follow, you can
> just add the line as a sibling to other existing settings.)

For example, in your workspace's *.vscode/settings.json*:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/path/to/your/custom/python"
}
```

I recommend reloading VS Code after setting the `pythonPath`. If it works, every time you open the workspace, it will automatically use that Python interpreter.

Comment: Weird, i did that through `Ctrl + ,` added the path including `.exe` but when I do `CTRL + Shift + P` > `Select Python Interpreter` it still doesn't list that.

Comment: Never mind, I've realized that after doing those steps, it was showing up, but when I clicked enter it would select the first entry and replace it with current (being the edited ne from python.pythonPath)

Comment: `"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "${command:python.interpreterPath}"`,

I think that might be more dynamic option

Answer (score 0):

As Vscode is updated or so, the setting has changed to this:

```
{
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/path/to/your/interpreter/python"
}
```